# Why does it keep redirecting back and forth when logged in?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, firebase-authentication

So I was making my application using Next JS 14, shadcn/ui and Firebase. I made a Sign In feature because this app required authentication. I used `signInWithPopup` to sign in the user and then redirected it to the `/home` route.

In my `src/app/page.tsx` file, where i put my sign in, I added a check that makes it so that if the user is signed in, then redirect them to the `/home` route. Meanwhile, in my `src/app/home/page.tsx` directory, I added a check to see if the user was not signed in, and if so, it would redirect them to the `/` directory.

Here's my code:

```
// src/app/page.tsx

"use client";

import { useEffect } from "react";

import {
  Card,
  CardContent,
  CardDescription,
  CardHeader,
  CardTitle
} from "@/components/ui/card";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";

import {
  FaGoogle,
  FaGithub,
  FaFacebook
} from "react-icons/fa";

import { app } from "@/lib/firebase";
import {
  getAuth,
  signInWithPopup,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  GithubAuthProvider,
  FacebookAuthProvider
} from "firebase/auth";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function Home() {
  const auth = getAuth(app);
  const router = useRouter();
  const [user, loading] = useAuthState(auth);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      window.location.href = "/home";
    }
  }, [user]);

  const withGoogle = () => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then(() => {
        router.push("/home");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("An error occured: " + err);
      });
  }

  const withGithub = () => {
    const provider = new GithubAuthProvider();

    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then(() => {
        router.push("/home");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("An error occured: " + err);
      });
  }

  const withFacebook = () => {
    const provider = new FacebookAuthProvider();

    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then(() => {
        router.push("/home");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("An error occured: " + err);
      });
  }

  return (
    <main>
      {loading || user ? (
        <p> Loading... </p>
      ) : (
        <div className="flex justify-center pt-64">
          <Card className="w-96">
            <CardHeader>
              <CardTitle> Sign In </CardTitle>
              <CardDescription>
                Sign in using one of these methods
              </CardDescription>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardContent>
              <div>
                <Button onClick={withGoogle}>
                  <FaGoogle className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" /> Sign In with Google
                </Button>
              </div>
              <div className="pt-3">
                <Button onClick={withGithub}>
                  <FaGithub className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" /> Sign In with Github
                </Button>
              </div>
              <div className="pt-3">
                <Button onClick={withFacebook}>
                  <FaFacebook className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" /> Sign In with Facebook
                </Button>
              </div>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </div>
      )}
    </main>
  )
}
```

```
// src/app/home/page.tsx

"use client";

import { app } from "@/lib/firebase";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";

import { useEffect } from "react";

function Home() {
  const auth = getAuth(app);
  const [user, loading] = useAuthState(auth);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) {
      window.location.href = "/";
    }
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <div>
      {loading || !user ? (
        <p> Loading... </p>
      ) : (
        <p> Hi Mom </p>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should **wait** for the user to load before you redirect, because the user is always **false** by default.

```
// src/app/home/page.tsx

  ...
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading && !user) {
      window.location.href = "/";
    }
  }, [user,loading]);
  ...
```